# dot1x 802.1x wired eth0 wpa_supplicant auto-start

Tags: raspbian, networking, ethernet, wpa-supplicant

Is there a possibility to start *wpa_supplicant* every time when the network connection comes up?

I am able to Secure the network connection manual, but not automatically.

My */etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf*

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
ap_scan=0
network={
    key_mgmt=IEEE8021X
    eap=PEAP
    identity="user"
    password="pasword"
    phase2="autheap=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

To start the connection with this command:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wired -i eth0
```

I tried to edit /etc/network/interfaces --> after reboot no network (also no lo)

I tried to write a small sh script in /etc/network/if-up.d/ --> booting takes about 10 minutes, also no network

Pls help me.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. wpa_supplicant is starting on bootup and managed associate, connect, disconnect wifi connections securely with encryption by your choice. So what?

Answer (score 1):

In your question you have wpa_supplicant trying to start Ethernet (eth0) and not WiFi (wlan0) - so I'm a bit baffled and assumed you want to start WiFi if Ethernet is down.

> sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wired -i eth0

You could try something like this ***(UNTESTED CODE)***:

```
target="8.8.8.8"
router="192.168.1.1"

/bin/ping -q -c1 $target > /dev/null

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    /usr/bin/killall -v wpa_supplicant
    sleep 1
    /usr/bin/killall -v wpa_supplicant
    sleep 2
    /sbin/wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -I wlan0
fi
```

Run this as root via CRON or even in a permanent loop

NOTE: I'm not able to test this at the mo as the family are at home and using the network :-)

You may need to reset the default route - not sure without testing...